# How to group foreach result the same value PHP

Tags: php

Please help me on how to group the value from foreach result:

```
 foreach ($result as  $value) {
        $group = $value['Barcode'];   
        echo $group.'<br>';
    }
```

- the result of this:

  9822550005004
   9822550005004
   9844660005002
   9844660005002
   9844660005002
   9844660005002

  My expected result would be:

  9822550005004
   9844660005002

Comment: `$arr = array_unique(array_column($result, 'Barcore')); echo implode(" ", $arr);`

Comment: Are you fethcing this values from a database? If answer is yes, please tell me what is your database (e.g. MySQL) and what is the API you use (e.g. MySQLi)?

Comment: Typo mistake: `$arr = array_unique(array_column($result, 'Barcode')); echo implode(" ", $arr)`

Comment: Im fetching this from webservices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use foreach and external array for getting the output like you want.

Using the foreach loop you need to store the each value in an array, here i store the value to the `$arr` array and makes the key as same as the value, cause yuo need the unique values, after storing the values just implode them with suitable delimiter `space` and get the desire output.

```
$arr = array();
foreach($result as $value){
    $arr[$value['Barcode']] = $value['Barcode'];
}
echo implode(" ", $arr); //9822550005004 9844660005002
```

Using Array functions...

`array_column` Get all the columns from the array as name `Barcode` and makes anther array of them, After that `array_unique` choose the unique values from the returned array and also make another array of it. So now you need to implode them as you want. The implode method makes the array as string with a delimiter. Here i use `space`.

```
$arr = array_unique(array_column($result, "Barcode"));
echo implode(" ", $arr); //9822550005004 9844660005002
```

Comment: Thanks all I get what I want already using @Frayne Konok  method. Thanks